# How to find the total no of result from following string

Tags: php

How to find the  total no of result from following string! in php

```
"Showing 1 - 24 of 6,200 Results"
```

Comment: You question is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is sort of incomplete.

If what you are asking is how to extract `6200` from the string `"Showing 1 - 24 of 6,200 Results` you can do:

```
$total = preg_replace('/\D/','',preg_replace('/^.*of (\S+) Results/','\1',$str));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you were asking for a regular expression, try

```
$total = (int) preg_replace('|(Showing\s[0-9]+\s\-[0-9]+\sof\s(([1-9][0-9]*),)?([0-9])\sResults)|','$3$4',"Showing 1 - 24 of 6,200 Results");
```

This returns the total number as integer.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
$str = "Showing 1 - 24 of 6,200 Results";
preg_match_all('!\d+!', str_replace(",", "", $str), $matches);
echo end($matches[0]);
```